# How can I vertically align content within a <p> tag inside of a div?

Tags: html, css

I can't for the life of me seem to get my links to vertically align inside of my div tag. I have tried with li and ul tags, but from what I read, it is even more difficult. Ideally, I want to be able to add more links and have them automatically align themselves as links are added/removed.

Here is my HTML: http://pastebin.com/9q4tzCpQ
Here is my CSS: http://pastebin.com/pBYxME7p

Thanks for any help I can get!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, I put your code in a fiddle but nothing stood out. http://jsfiddle.net/7stcb/

Answer (score -1):

Vertical align doesn't work unless you are inside of a table. If its absolutely critical, and the content is static, use position absolute.

Position absolute fixes the position of a tag such as p, relative to its next non-static ancestor. So basically, in your div tag, put

```
position:relative;
```

and in your p tag use

```
position:absolute;
top:90%;
left:5%
```

remember: position:absolute specifies distance *from* so top:20px, moves it *down* 20px.

google: position attribute.

Good Luck!

Comment: Not true at all... you can easily do 'display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;' in pure css.

Comment: Thanks bwheeler96! Your suggestion worked, but it didn't work in the way that I needed it since the amount of links that will fill the div will be unknown, which would require me changing the percentages to make them fit. I appreciate the help though!